# Own build native module does not get found in electron

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron, native

So, i followed this tutorial ([click](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/native-extensions-for-node-js-767e221b3d26)), as I need some custom cpp code executed in my electron app. I could perfectly build it and when I run `node index.js`, I get my hello world output. But when I use it in my electron app, then build module does not get found and I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at Function.getFileName (C:\Users\simon\WebstormProjects\w3champions-launcher\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:178)
    at bindings (C:\Users\simon\WebstormProjects\w3champions-launcher\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:82)
    at eval (App.vue?ec60:19)
    at Module../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts& (app.js:938)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (App.vue?96c8:1)
    at Module../src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts& (app.js:1329)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
getFileName @ C:\Users\simon\WebstormProjects\w3champions-launcher\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:178
bindings @ C:\Users\simon\WebstormProjects\w3champions-launcher\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:82
eval @ App.vue?ec60:19
./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts& @ app.js:938
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:849
fn @ app.js:151
eval @ App.vue?96c8:1
./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts& @ app.js:1329
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:849
fn @ app.js:151
eval @ App.vue?bff9:1
./src/App.vue @ app.js:1317
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:849
fn @ app.js:151
eval @ main.ts:11
./src/main.ts @ app.js:1916
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:849
fn @ app.js:151
1 @ app.js:2061
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:849
checkDeferredModules @ app.js:46
(anonymous) @ app.js:925
(anonymous) @ app.js:928
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8440 You are running Vue in devel
```

I had similar problems with other modules before and I could always solve them, by marking them as external dependencies in my `vue.config.js`. But with my built module this does not seem to work. It looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      externals: [... 'hello-world', ...],
    }
  }
}
```

Do I have to do something else here? Dont know why this module is not found...

edit: I just found out, that I can require it like this:

```
const hello_world = require('./build/Release/hello-world')
console.log(hello_world.sayHi());
```

and then it works. But this is a little dumb, i would say. Is there something else I can do? Also the build does not work like this, as the build package has the modules somewhere else.

Comment: The [bindings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bindings) package may help you avoid specifying the full path to the .node library.

Comment: Yes, I used this, but that did always result in an "index out of bounds exception" in bindings.js.  Here is some more detail: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/5233 I have a solution now, that is pretty hacky but works (also for code signing). I will post it it later

Comment: Can you please provide further info?

Comment: I think the solution was the edit that I made to the post. I dont think I solved it properly, as far as I remember. But that has been some time back.